# Result id from database by mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a column in database saved as id like 1,12,10 and I want to return only one id like 1 or 12 or 10 when use like will return wrong data? What can I do?

Comment: ... what? You're not making much sense.

Comment: Are you really in that much of a hurry to ask a question that you can't even spend 10 seconds to at least attempt to spell-check it and ask it in such a way that other people can understand it?

Comment: The real question you should be asking is - How do I mark an answer as correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`LIMIT`](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-limit.html).

```
SELECT col FROM table_name LIMIT 1
```

This will only return one result.

However you are claiming that it is returning the wrong results, which we can't help if you don't post more.

### Update

as per your comment, you want to use [`IN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

```
SELECT col FROM table_name WHERE id IN (10, 12, 1)
```

Comment: Glad you could get a question out of that.

Comment: i know limit . i want return all result where id like 10 or 12 or 1. the problem column saved a lot of id like (12,10,1)